# Nodejs, sent post insert values to database but after this, browser waiting for locahost.

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, insert

Trying insert value to mysql database, so far I can insert values, but after insert, browser have infinite loop with "Waiting for localhost". I was trying to close connection - con.end(); but this does not solve issue.

```
app.post('/insert', function(req, res) {
  currentdate = req.body.date;
  weight = req.body.weight;
  console.log("Connected!");
  var sql = "INSERT INTO WEIGHT_LOG (DATE, WEIGHT) VALUES ('" + currentdate + "', '" + weight + "')";
  con.query(sql, function(err, result) {
    if (err) throw err;
    console.log(sql);
    console.log("1 record inserted");
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You method isn't never responding with nothing.

You have to call `res.status(200).send()` to respond with HTTP 200 status code and close the connection with your client.
You should check [Express documentation](http://expressjs.com/it/api.html#res) to understand how middlewares works.

Also, you are confusing your "con" database object with the connection between your HTTP server and the client. By calling `con.end()` you are closing the connection between your HTTP Server and the database.